# How to use BottomSheet inside model

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I want to add **bottom sheet** in `Modal`. I am using `reanimated-bottom-sheet` and react native modal.

But when I use `BottomSheet` inside `Modal` gesture not work and can't close`BottomSheet` with swiping down.

I searched and I found this is `RCGH` problem.

So I decide to use `View` instead of `Modal`.

but `View` doesn't cover `Header`.

This is bottomSheet code:

```
<View style={BottomSheetStyles.container}>
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={handleOutsidePress}>
    <Animated.View style={[BottomSheetStyles.dropShadow, { opacity }]} />
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  <Animated.Code exec={onChange(position, [cond(eq(position, 1), call([], onClose))])} />
  <BottomSheet
    ref={sheet}
    initialSnap={zeroIndex}
    snapPoints={snapPoints}
    callbackNode={position}
    renderHeader={() => <View style={BottomSheetStyles.header} />}
    renderContent={() => (
      <View style={[BottomSheetStyles.content, { height: "100%" }]}>{children}</View>
    )}
  />
</View>
```

and this is styles:

```
const BottomSheetStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        flex: 1,
        zIndex: 100,
    },
    dropShadow: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        flex: 1,
        zIndex: 100,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)",
    },
    header: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.greyC4C,
        width: 90,
        height: 7,
        margin: 5,
        alignSelf: "center",
        borderRadius: 11,
    },
    content: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.whiteFFF,
        paddingTop: 18,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 22,
        borderTopRightRadius: 22,
    },
});
```

So problem can be solve either whit solving gesture in `Modal` or do something to cover `Header` with `View`.

I am using `React Navigation`.